Can "spank" be used in relation to other body parts, or is it used only in relation to the buttocks?
I would like to ask for the opinion of native speakers of English regarding a dictionary definition of the verb "spank".
According to the Wiktionary, the meaning of the verb "spank" is "to beat, smack or slap a person's buttocks or other vulnerable body part like the cheeks, with the bare hand or other object, as punishment, or for sexual gratification".
I have always thought that "spank" is used only in relation to the buttocks. It sounds strange to me that "spank" can be used in relation to the cheeks/face.
Regarding the body part, some dictionaries define “spank” as “to slap on the buttocks as for punishment”. According to this definition, “spank” is used only in relation to the buttocks. On the other hand, some dictionary define “spank” as “to slap especially on the buttocks”. The word “especially” in the definition suggests that “spank” is used mainly in relation to the buttocks but probably it could be used in relation to other body parts as well. It says “especially”, not “exclusively”.
According to your language experience, understanding and feeling regarding the word “spank”, can "spank" be used in relation to other body parts, or is it used only in relation to the buttocks?
In case it can be used in relation to other body parts, do the following sentences with the "spank" in relation to different body parts sound acceptable/natural to native English speakers:

She spanked the child on the face.
She spanked the child on the hand.
She spanked the child on the legs/thighs.


The first sentence is usually expressed as She slapped the child's face.

I do not (necessarily) mean to be critical, but many native speakers may find your very frequent use of that word a little excessive ( I mean 'creepy'), considering that it is notoriously interesting to perverts, and your question can be expressed in much fewer words.

It is a linguistic question, not in a sexual or perverse sense. I am trying to understand the exact meaning of the word. I have always thought that "spank" is used only in relation to the buttocks. It sounds strange to me that "spank" can be used in relation to the cheeks/face, as the the Wiktionary definition states. It sounds brutal and unnatural to me. Also, I am asking about the other body parts because I would like to know what its exact usage is and in fact if there is a real difference between "slap" and "spank".

I wouldn't trust Wiktionary.  It is fast-and-loose with evidence. The entry shows a political cartoon from 1860 where a man is being struck on the rump with a switch and say that it depicts him being spanked. Merriam-Webster: "a sharp slap or blow to the buttocks usually with the palm of the hand" to which we could add "or a series of such slaps or blows".

@MichaelHarvey  You must be recalling that infamous line from The Grinch at the Roxy:   "...spink, spank,  spunk."

@TimR - no, more that when I was a boy, there were these shops in London that sold little black-and-white photo 'spanking magazines'. You saw them in the window as you walked by. A kind of fetish interest.

You can smack... [anything from a person to the head of a nail] ...with... [a hand, fist, hammer, shovel, etc.]. But you'd be very unlikely to slap / spank [something] with [something else].

I think you can say "to slap something on something" like in the sentence "He slapped his wallet on the table", but you cannot use "spank" in this way. Regarding the meaning of the verb "spank", is the following opinion (of a non native English speaker) logical? The verb "spank" (and the noun "a spanking" respectively) implies a repeated action (a series of slaps) which is done in order to punish someone (usually a child) without causing injuries. That is why a spanking is typically applied on the bottom, and saying something like "spanking on the face or on other body part" sounds strange.

British men often indulge in an amusement called 'spanking the monkey'.

@TimR - I recall the George character in Blackadder Goes Forth asking 'When are we going to give Fritz a taste of our British spunk?'

No. Broadly, if it's not on the buttocks, then the victim is not 'spanked'  but 'slapped' or 'smacked'.
'Spanked' might be extended to apply to the upper thighs but then, only to the back of the upper thighs and 'upper' would be vital.

If you said that someone placed his wallet on the table, and gave it a good spanking, I think most people would immediately understand what was meant. Furthermore, many butchers, chefs and cooks talk about 'spanking' or 'slapping' raw meat to improve its texture when cooked. This may provoke hilarity on social media (see 'spanking the monkey' above).

@RobbieGoodwin - I understand that "spanking" is a traditionally established way of punishing children by slapping them with the open hand on their bottoms (or on the back of the upper thighs). What if someone punishes a child by slapping him/her on the front of thighs? Could it be called a spanking? The action is similar (slapping with the open hand) and the reason for it is the same (a punishment). If not, does it mean that a punishment consisting of slapping the font of the thighs cannot be called "a spanking" because it does not fall within the concept of how a child should be punished?

Spank has a particular context, to hit as a punishment for a child (or secondarily for sexual gratification), so if talking about a child its use will be conditioned by what punishment you consider appropriate for a child (and with an adult it will depend on whether you're willing to consider sexual gratification and what people find arousing.) Children are normally only hit openhandedly on the backside (other pain may be applied elsewhere). Similarly poke typically means to push something soft, so it's applied to soft body parts, and slap to body parts that make a slapping noise.

@StuartF - Thanks. I am trying to understand if the meaning of "spank" (for a child) is lingustically limited in relation to certain body parts (the bottom and the back of the upper thighs as Robbie Goodwin pointed out) or it depends on what a person considers appropriete for a child. Does it mean that, for instance, a punishment consisting of slapping the front of the thighs could be called "a spanking" by some native English speakers because they consider it an appropriate punishment for a child? Or is "spank" lingustically limited only to the bottom for all speakers of English?

@MichaelHarvey I think this question is fine. While there are all sorts of unsavory connotations with "spank" in other contexts, this question is clearly about its use regarding corporeal punishment (and it's done without taking a side on that, a controversial subject in itself). If the text here is awkward or repetitive (I personally don't see any major issues though), it can certainly be attributed to the fact that a learner wrote it, and not something more sinister.

@Laurel Yes, exactly - except I hope you meant not 'corporeal' but 'corporal'!

If someone punished a child by slapping on the front of the thighs that could  not properly be called a spanking, though very few of us would mind the mis-use.
Almost separately, that has nothing to do with any concept of how a child should be punished. One is a simple physical action; the other is a hugely complicated conceptual argument.

@MichaelHarvey - Now I understand your reaction to my question. It helped me understand how native British speakers assume "spank". I spoke with a native speaker about it and he advised me to avoid this word because for the British ear it has sexual overtones and many British people tend to think of fetishism when they hear it. In the context of children it is better to use "smack". In his opinion, "smacking children" sounds better than "spanking children". On the other hand, in the American English, "spanking children" soudns fine and "smack" could sound abusive like in "smack in the head".

Edit
Although spank on the face is found in Google Books,  this use is rare and is highly unlikely.  Slap is more common.
Similarly,  spank on the legs is rare.
The nouns slap and to a lesser extent smack are more common than spank  and are used for various body parts.  Here spank appears only with the body part the OP mentioned several times, but a better word is used.
To use SPANK as an object, the gerund participle form is more likely, as in I gave him a spanking.
As for usage as verbs, slap, smack, and spank are compared, and spank is the least common.  To say 'VERB him on the face', SLAP is the most common; 'SPANK him on the face' is not found in Ngram.

Note that spank is very rarely used as a noun, so whereas I gave him a slap and I gave him a smack are both perfectly common and natural, I gave him a spank is extremely unlikely. We use the gerund noun form I gave him a spanking. See this usage chart for the nouns used in I'll give you a spank, spanking, smack, smacking.

spank on the face may be in google books, it's still not on, as the Brits say.

Thanks, @FumbleFingers and Lambie.  I have edited my answer.

There are a handful of instances of spanked my arm in Google Books, but they're all very recent, and I wouldn't rule out the possibility that most (or even all) of them are from non-native Anglophone writers.

@FumbleFingers - this is probably not funny to Americans the way it is to Brits - If you've heard Katie talk about spanking the turkey for Thanksgiving, here's a little snippet of her

@MichaelHarvey: Well, it seems that spank the monkey originated early C20 in the US. I confess I always assumed Peter Gabriel's Shock the monkey was a somewhat risque variant thereof, but after briefly scanning the Wikipedia page, I see I was mistaken. I'm still not sure what he did mean by it, though.

@FumbleFingers - I was probably thinking of bash the bishop which is pretty much UK only, I think? Maybe the Ozzies/Kiwis know about it?

@MichaelHarvey Did you notice neither 'bash the bishop' nor more relevantly 'spank the monkey' actually involves any 'spanking' action?
All three involve moving parts of the arm up and down, but isn't that the end of their similarity?

@RobbieGoodwin - yes, I suppose I did.
